# Is There Any Way To Find Highest High Between Two Conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How To Find Highest High In Between Cond1 and Cond2

```
Cond1= ta.crossover(close,A)
Cond2= ta.corssunder(close,A)

HighestHigh= ta.pivothigh(high, leftbars= Cond1 , rightbars= Cond2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a `var` variable that indicates you can start looking at the highest high. This variable should become `true` whenever `Cond1` is `true` and should become `false` whenever `Cond2` is `true`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

sma_fast = ta.sma(close, 20)
sma_slow = ta.sma(close, 200)

plot(sma_fast, color=color.green)
plot(sma_slow, color=color.red)

var can_find = false

cond_start = ta.crossover(sma_fast, sma_slow)
cond_stop = ta.crossunder(sma_fast, sma_slow)

bgcolor(cond_start ? color.new(color.green, 85) : na)
bgcolor(cond_stop ? color.new(color.red, 85) : na)

can_find := cond_stop ? false : cond_start ? true : can_find

var float highest_high = na

highest_high := if (cond_start)
    high
else if (can_find)
    if (high > highest_high)
        high
    else
        highest_high
else
    na

plot(highest_high, color=color.yellow, style=plot.style_circles)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks It Is Giving Us The Highs Above The Said Condition But How To Get The Highest High In Between  Condition1 and Condition 2

Comment: Kindly See The Image For Clarity 

https://www.tradingview.com/x/yGVtfyUx/

Comment: It already works like that. Just change the conditions.